# Trying to use environment variable to hide my api key in my fetch link React JS

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, fetch, api-key

I'm trying to use a environment variable to hide my api_key in my fetch link but it doesn't work and still read it as undefined. Could somebody help me ?

```
I create this project with : npx create-react-app my-app
```

```
  const fetchMovies = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setMovies(data.results);
      });
  };

my .env file:

REACT_APP_API_KEY=<API-KEY-GOES-HERE>
```

[image]

I was expecting to have my fetch fonction working as usual

Comment: You cannot hide API key on the frontend. If you don't want to expose your API key on UI, you will have to create a backend and call the API there and send the results to UI.

Comment: where do you store .env file

Comment: After adding the environment variable did you try restarting the project? and also what is the location .env file is located.

Comment: I stored it in root folder ? Is it right ? Yes I did restart the project